# Telegram bot sendPhoto not working

Tags: php, telegram-bot

**What I'm trying to do** is retrieving profile photos from a user and sned them for another, all by PHP.

**The problem is** when I send photos using `file_id` string, all of the photos sent to user are the same single picture!

I've not really run that but I'm sending my own photos to myself for testing the functionality and the result is my current telegram profile picture, every time.

**My code:**

```
<?php
define('my_id', '12345678');

$userPhotos = apiRequestJson("getUserProfilePhotos", array('user_id' => my_id, 'offset' => 0, 'limit' => 1));

apiRequestJson("sendPhoto", array('chat_id' => my_id, 'photo' => $userPhotos['photos'][0][0]['file_id']));
apiRequestJson("sendPhoto", array('chat_id' => my_id, 'photo' => $userPhotos['photos'][0][1]['file_id']));
?>
```

**Link to the telegram bot api:** https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

I'd be thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First of all, when in the request you set the `limit` parameter to `1`, you request for **only one** photo. Simply remove the optional `offset` and `limit` parameters to retrieve first 100 photos:

```
$userPhotos = apiRequestJson( 'getUserProfilePhotos', array( 'user_id' => my_id ) );
```

Second problem: the returned response is an “Array of Array of *PhotoSize*”, that means an array of photos that are arrays of different photo sizes:

```
$userPhotos['photos'][0][0]['file_id']
                      │  │
              photos ─┘  └─ photo sizes
```

You iterate second index (the size of same photo); you have instead to iterate first index:

```
apiRequestJson( 'sendPhoto', array( 'chat_id' => my_id, 'photo' => $userPhotos['photos'][0][0]['file_id'] ) );
apiRequestJson( 'sendPhoto', array( 'chat_id' => my_id, 'photo' => $userPhotos['photos'][1][0]['file_id'] ) );
```

Since you don't know in advance the total photo number of each user, the best way is to iterate through a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach( $userPhotos['photos'] as $photo )
{
    apiRequestJson( 'sendPhoto', array( 'chat_id' => my_id, 'photo' => $photo[0]['file_id'] ) );
}
```

Last but not least, please note that with this request you retrieve the **user profile** photos, so in most cases you will obtain anyway only one photo.

Comment: Thanke you @fusion3k, that did it! I really appreciated for your comprehensive answer.